# What is the purpose of this transistor switch on the line providing VCC to this SMPS controller?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, vcc

In this SMPS for white goods, the VCC pin 5 of U3 ([LD7537](https://www.leadtrend.com.tw/images/cgcustom/img020201215115222.pdf)) is initially fed from AC Mains through R54, R55 and R53 and once started it is fed from the auiliary winding (N2) of transformer (T1) through R66, R67 and D19.
[image: smps q10]

Why is there a transistor Q10 ([MMBT4401](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/1/MMBT4401_D-2316326.pdf)) and the diode Q6 ([BAV70](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAV70_SER.pdf)) along the line from the auiliary winding to the VCC? The datasheet of U3 doesn't mention the use of such a circuit. What purpose does it serve and how does it work?

Comment: That is power supply for U1. It is permanently feeding U1. Chain of resistor R53-55 only for starting. Q6 prevents back current to transistor.

Comment: ZD3 and Q10 form a crude voltage regulator (zener reference + emitter follower). Q6 blocks reverse current flow during startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q10 and ZD3 for a classic circuit known as series pass voltage reulator.
The output voltage will be equal to ZD3 mins the Q10 Vbe voltage.

Answer (score 2):

U1 is permanently fed from auxillary winding via that voltage stabilizer. Chain of R53-55 just feed IC at starting main power.